# Create new variable based on other variables

Tags: r, dataframe, categories

Working in R, I have a data frame with three variables that look like this:

```
  var1        var2        var3       
1 0.695783133 0.009036145 0.02409639 
2 0.651006711 0.348993289 0.00000000 
3 1.000000000 0.000000000 0.00000000 
4 0.404185022 0.575991189 0.00000000 
5 0.004863813 0.736381323 0.25097276 
6 0.833827893 0.074183976 0.06231454
```

I want to add a fourth variable (`var4`) whose value will be based on the value of the original three variables (`var1`, `var2`, `var3`) in the following way:

If `var1` >= 0.5, `var4` = 1

If `var2` >= 0.5, `var4` = 2

If `var3` >= 0.5, `var4` = 3

If no variable is >= 0.5, `var4` = 4

E.g. like this:

```
  var1        var2        var3       var4
1 0.695783133 0.009036145 0.02409639 1
2 0.651006711 0.348993289 0.00000000 1
3 1.000000000 0.000000000 0.00000000 1
4 0.404185022 0.575991189 0.00000000 2
5 0.004863813 0.736381323 0.25097276 2
6 0.833827893 0.074183976 0.06231454 1
```

I'm confident that there is a simple way to this, but I can't figure it out since I'm pretty new to R. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that var1 is at first position, var2 in second and so on, then you can use `max.col` along with an `ifelse` to catch your last condition, i.e.

```
ifelse(rowSums(df >= 0.5) == 0, 4, max.col(df >= 0.5))
#if 0.5 is the maximum value then ifelse(rowSums(df >= 0.5) == 0,4,max.col(df)) will also do
#1 2 3 4 5 6 
#1 1 1 2 2 1
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. I figured it would be necessary to use the `ifelse` to catch my last condition, but didn't get it to work when I wrote it myself. Thanks again!

Comment: @m.ras `ifelse` is not a necessity, `max.col(df >= 0.5, ties.method = "first") + 3*(rowSums(df >= 0.5) == 0)` should give the same output

Comment: @Jaap Thanks! I will try that as well.

Comment: @Jaap I tried your suggestion and it works great as well. However, I don't fully understand what the second part of your script does (i.e. the `+ 3*(rowSums(df >= 0.5) == 0)` part). More specifically, why do you take `3*` the `rowSums` function? Would you mind explaining this to me or point me in the right direction where I can read more about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
 df <- read.table(text=" var1        var2        var3       
            1 0.695783133 0.009036145 0.02409639 
            2 0.651006711 0.348993289 0.00000000 
            3 1.000000000 0.000000000 0.00000000 
            4 0.404185022 0.575991189 0.00000000 
            5 0.004863813 0.736381323 0.25097276 
            6 0.833827893 0.074183976 0.06231454 ")
 df%>%
   mutate(var4=case_when(
     var1>=.5 ~ 1,
     var2>=.5 ~ 2,
     var3>=.5 ~ 3,
     T~4))
         var1        var2       var3 var4
1 0.695783133 0.009036145 0.02409639    1
2 0.651006711 0.348993289 0.00000000    1
3 1.000000000 0.000000000 0.00000000    1
4 0.404185022 0.575991189 0.00000000    2
5 0.004863813 0.736381323 0.25097276    2
6 0.833827893 0.074183976 0.06231454    1
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provide data for us to work with, use dput().

But, perhaps something like this using dplyr.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(var4 = case_when (var1 >= 0.5 ~ 1,
                           var2 >= 0.5 ~ 2,
                           var3 >= 0.5 ~ 3,
                           TRUE ~ 4)
```

Comment: what is `=>`, do you mean `>=` ?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I mean. Changed now.

Answer (score 0):

Using Base r  ifelse will do the trick

```
df_test<- read.table(text= "var1        var2        var3       
1 0.695783133 0.009036145 0.02409639 
2 0.651006711 0.348993289 0.00000000 
3 1.000000000 0.000000000 0.00000000 
4 0.404185022 0.575991189 0.00000000 
5 0.004863813 0.736381323 0.25097276 
6 0.833827893 0.074183976 0.06231454 ",header = T)

df_test$var4 <- ifelse(df_test$var1 > 0.5,1,ifelse(df_test$var2 > 0.5,2,ifelse(df_test$var3 > 0.5,3,4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible like this:

```
sapply(apply(df >= .5, 1, which), function(x) if(length(x)) x[1] else 4)
```

Comment: @AndreElrico Sorry about that. Will make sure to provide better data next time I post. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Sotos it does now